# two-way binding in angular4

Tags: angular

I have an input field and two buttons:

```
<md-input-container><input mdInput [(ngModel)]="row.goalStatusName"></md-input-container>
<button md-icon-button>
    <md-icon (click)="modifyGoalStatusName(row)">done</md-icon>
</button>
<button md-icon-button>
    <md-icon (click)="modifyGoalStatusName(row)" >clear</md-icon>
</button>
```

When `saved` button is clicked, I want to pass the changed `goalStatusName` value from input box which is obtained by two-way binding.
However, if `clear` button is clicked, I wish to pass the original unchanged `goalStatusName` value.

Things I tried:
I disabled two-way binding so that value is not changed if clear button is clicked however, in that case I am not able to pass updated value from input box: `<input mdInput [ngModel]="row.goalStatusName">`

I am using this in an angular material `md-cell` and as such not able to retrieve value from input fields.

Comment: You need to store the original value yourself somewhere. Angular doesn't maintain some initial state for you. You can fetch all values for all input elements of a form at once if that is desired.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I thought of that but decided against it looking for some better way (if any).....Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnChanges` lifecycle hook. As mentioned in [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges), you can get the old and new value on change in that model. Sample code below:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  prop: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```